# Helm Configmap setting labels

Tags: kubernetes-helm, configmap

I am trying to set a label based on the value in a Configmap but Helm validate says the value is Nil. This is set..

For example, something like this.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: {{ $fullname := printf "%s-%s" .Release.Name .Chart.Name | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" }}
  name: {{ $fullname }}
  labels:
    tags.example.com/env: {{ .configMap.myConfigMap.data.ENV }}
```

I know the value works as setting values here works

```
  containers:
  - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
    image: "{{ .Values.image }}"
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent          
    env:
    - name: ENV
      valueFrom:
        configMapKeyRef:
          name: myConfigMap
          key: ENV
```

So we can see the Helm goo to get data from a Configmap using "valueFrom". But how do I do I set other values within the Chart, for example the Label

```
labels:
    tags.example.com/env: {{ .configMap.myConfigMap.data.ENV }}
```

Comment: Can you use a native Helm value here, instead of trying to look up the value from somewhere else?  What should `.configMap` refer to?

Comment: configMap is me giving an example. I am referring to the Helm object type "configmap". AKA if I have a configmap called "myConfigMap" with Data called ENV, how do I put the value into the label. What do you mean by "native Helm"?

Answer (score 1):

The Helm templating layer cannot refer to arbitrary objects that the chart is creating.  You're proposing a syntax to look up a field in a ConfigMap that's elsewhere in the chart, and that simply doesn't exist.

The input to a Helm chart is a structured map of [values](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#values-files).  Your chart can define and use any values it likes; you're not limited to the values that the prototype chart includes.  So if your chart's `values.yaml` file contains

```yaml
# env is the name of the environment this is running in.
env: development
```

then your template can say

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    tags.example.com/env: {{ .Values.env }}
spec:
  containers:
    - env:
        - name: ENV
          value: {{ .Values.env }}
```

With Helm there is a legitimate style choice whether to use a ConfigMap at all here.  If the chart is also going to create the ConfigMap with a set of values that are basically fixed, there's not really a difference between specifying them as part of the Deployment directly or inserting a ConfigMap in between.  (Personally if I'm just setting an environment variable directly from a Helm value I tend to not use a ConfigMap.)

Newer versions of Helm do include a [`lookup`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-lookup-function) function that could get a value out of a ConfigMap, but I'd recommend avoiding it.  It's a complex setup, it makes your installation non-deterministic depending on what already exists in the cluster, and there's not a clear story on how to update your deployment if the configured value changes.  Using Helm's standard values mechanism will be simpler and clearer.

Comment: I understand the use of a values.yaml file, and I use this for unique values for the Pod. However, every pod within a Namespace has the same setting - always. Therefore it's a waste to set this in the values for every chart, when the value can come from a single configmap location. Change once, change everywhere.

Comment: The object metadata won't update itself automatically, even if you use `lookup`.  If you `kubectl edit configmap` with the global values, you'll have to `helm update` every release in the namespace by hand.  If you have to do that anyways, putting the values into a shared `helm install -f` values file might be clearer than using the external ConfigMap.

Comment: going off track here. But I am using Terraform to manage thousands of pods across 5 different custom charts, In Terraform, when I update a configmap, it refreshes all pods/charts that use it automatically. This is build into a CI/CD pipeline. I have "fixed" this by using a .Values.env but I see no reason why configMapKeyRef can only be used with container/env. Why can't I set a Label based on this... Helm/k8s clearly does have access to the value in the Chart.

Answer (score 0):

thanx to @david-maze for sending me in the right direction.

To solve this I have created a custom template that defines the variable. This in turn gets the value from a configmap

```
{{- define "mychart.env" -}}
{{- $configmap := (lookup "v1" "ConfigMap" "default" "myconfig") }}
{{- end -}}
```

Then I can therefore use Template value. This is cleaner as the lookup only exist in one place rather than in lots of templates. The Helper can also be shared across multiple charts... win win